# Recyclerview - OnCreateViewholder - How to return "null" if some condition

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Im struggling with some code and what i want to do is in some cases inflate a view, in other cases inflate another different view but in OTHER CASES ignore the register and don't inflate a view. So i wrote this. I am returning a view if i== 0, returning another view if i == 1 and i want to do NOTHING if i == 3. Same on BindViewHolder method, where case 3 do just nothing. Thanks!

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    if (i == 1){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View celda = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mag_slidingup_panelcontent_item_view, viewGroup, false);
    productViewHolder productViewHolder = new productViewHolder(celda);

    return productViewHolder;
    }else if (i == 0){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View celda = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_bottom_products_parent, viewGroup, false);
        productViewHolderParent productViewHolderParent = new productViewHolderParent(celda);

        return productViewHolderParent;
    }else
        return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            productViewHolderParent productViewHolderParent = (productViewHolderParent) viewHolder;
            productViewHolderParent.update(magProducts.get(i));
            break;
        case 1:
            productViewHolder productViewHolder = (productViewHolder) viewHolder;
            productViewHolder.update(magProducts.get(i));
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
}
```

error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Comment: You cannot return null there. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I have an array with "Products". With some functions i determine if this products are (each one) parent or child or alone. So if the Product is "parent"(i==0) i inflate that product layout. if the Product is "child" (i==1) i inflate that product layout that is different than the "parent" one. If the Product is "alone" (i == 3) i don't want to inflate a view. I want to ignore that product of the array.

Comment: Well, then those "alone" products shouldn't be in the list you're giving to the `Adapter`.

Comment: Please filter out the "alone" product from the product list, or you could define an empty layout and inflate that, but it is not recommended, the first approach is better.

Comment: Okey. I will try this. I just solved the problem with an empty view but it feels dirty. Thanks guys! Will update soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it.

In the comments they explained me that i can't return null and i should filtrate the list before passing it to the adapter. In my particular case i needed that data that i wanted to hide so i did what CodeRanger said. I inflated an empty view.

Thanks all!